# What input type should I use for an ISBN in an HTML form?

Tags: forms, html-input, isbn

I have a web form that asks the user to enter an ISBN number.  I want to design the input field so that it can handle either a 10 or 13 digit ISBN.  I also want it to work regardless of whether or not the user enters hyphens.  So when I create the form field below, what should I use for the question marked input type?  I have read that you should generally avoid text fields because of the possibility of SQL injection.  Type "number" won't work if the user puts in hyphens.  Is there any alternative to using "text" for the input type?  My database currently stores the ISBN as a varchar(17).

```
<form action="processform.php">
ISBN: <input type="???" name="ISBN"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Use text and properly sanitize and validate the data before inserting it into the database.

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is no "ISBN" type even in HTML5.

You may use regular expression ("pattern" attribute), but not all browsers support it (modern, how ever, do).

Comment: No input type is going to prevent SQL injection. SQL injection happens on the backend, the input is on the front end.

Answer (score 1):

I would take

```
 <input type="text">
```

Because you have chars and integer.